# Traveling Salesman (TSP) no return

Tags: traveling-salesman

Does someone know about a implementation of a variation of the TSP algorithm without the need of returning to the start point, but keeping the 'must-pass' requirement (with fixed start and end point)? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Btw, TSP stands for Traveling Salesman Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **Genetic Algorithms** to solve the TSP problem, you can **apply this restriction to the Genoms** (which usually are realized as arrays containing the visiting sequence of the villages).

- *Spawn* the Genoms with a fixed start and end point
- Make sure the start and end point are not altered on *mutation* and *crossover*
- Whether or not you return to the start point is within the realm of the *Fitness Function*, which interprets and rates the *Fitness* (inverse route length) of your *Genoms*.

This guarantees that any solution produced follows your requirements.

Comment: Do you know about some source code that I can use as a base to implement this variation of the TSP?

Comment: Generation5.org has Articles on that topic, explaing how to solve TSP with GAs: http://generation5.org/articles.asp?Action=List&Topic=Genetic+Algorithms